# Add console.profile statements to JavaScript/jQuery code on the fly

Tags: javascript, jquery

We have a thick client app using jQuery heavily and want to profile the performance of the code using firebug's console.profile API. The problem is, I don't want to change the code to write the profile statements. Take this example:

```
var search=function(){
    this.init=function(){
        console.log('init');
    }
    this.ajax=function(){
        console.log('ajax');
        //make ajax call using $.ajax and do some DOM manipulations here..
    }
    this.cache=function(){
        console.log('cache');
    }
}
var instance=new search();
instance.ajax();
```

I want to profile my instance.ajax method, but I dont want to add profile statements in the code, as that makes it difficult to maintain the code.

I'm trying to override the methods using closures, like this: http://www.novogeek.com/post/2010/02/27/Overriding-jQueryJavaScript-functions-using-closures.aspx but am not very sure how I can achieve. Any pointers on this? I think this would help many big projects to profile the code easily without a big change in code.

Here is the idea. Just run the below code in firebug console, to know what I'm trying to achieve.

```
var search=function(){
    this.init=function(){
        console.log('init');
    }
    this.ajax=function(){
        console.log('ajax');
        //make ajax call using $.ajax and do some DOM manipulations here..
    }
    this.cache=function(){
        console.log('cache');
    }
}
var instance=new search();

$.each(instance, function(functionName, functionBody){
    (function(){
        var dup=functionBody
        functionBody=function(){
            console.log('modifying the old function: ',functionName);
            console.profile(functionName);
            dup.apply(this,arguments);
            console.profileEnd(functionName);
        }
    })();
    console.log(functionName, '::', functionBody());
});
```

Now what I need is, if i say instance.ajax(), I want the new ajax() method to be called, along with the console.profile statements. Hope I'm clear with the requirement. Please improvise the above code.

Regards,
Krishna,
http://www.novogeek.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to modify the single instance of "search" then this should work:

```
$.each(instance, function(name, method){
    if (typeof method !== 'function') return;
    instance[name] = function() {
        console.profile(name);
        var ret = method.apply(this, arguments);
        console.profileEnd(name);
        return ret;
    };
});
```

Comment: Hi J-P,
Thanks for the quick reply. I missed out the return parameter. This is what I was looking for. So now I can assign this $.each to a variable(e.g., newInstance) and say newInstance.init() which modifies the original init and adds profile statements to it.

Comment: Hi James,
What if I have private functions in the same "search()" function? Obviously they wont be available under the instance. So is there a way we can handle this?

Comment: @novogeek, Not using this technique. To make it work on "private" functions you'd have to change them manually...

Comment: yeah..just wanted to get a confirmation. Thanx a lot James! I love your blog. Lots of stuff to learn!! :)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is from a long time ago but I wanted to add this in case other people find this answer. You can make anonymous/private functions work by adding a name to each one. The other comments mention doing it manually bit I wanted to explain how to:

`$('.stuff').each(function() { ... });`

to

`$('.stuff').each(function workOnStuff() { ... });`